# Problemas con un Virtualhost Apache 2

Tags: servidor, apache2, localhost, virtualhost

Hola estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de configurar un virtualhost en Apache, después de configurar todo y poner la dirección en chrome me lanza la búsqueda en google en lugar de visitar el virtualhost.

Os explico los pasos:

1 - He creado una carpeta en var/www/todo-empresa-tarea-daw02

2 - Dentro de etc/apache2/sites-available he creado un archivo llamado empresa-tarea-daw02.conf con el siguiente codigo.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/todo-empresa-tarea-daw02/
    ServerName www.empresa-tarea-daw02.local
    ServerAlias empresa-tarea-daw02.local

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

3 - He modificado el archivo /etc/hosts con el siguiente código:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   luis-Lenovo-Y50-70

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 www.empresa-tarea-daw02.local
```

4 - Luego he usado el comando sudo a2ensite empresa-tarea-daw02.conf
5 - He reseteado apache con sudo service apache2 restart

La carpeta tiene un index.html para probar

Gracias

Comment: Tiene www.empresa-tarea-daw02.local en su /etc/hosts o un lugar donde ella resuelve a 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Si esta configurado en el archivo hosts